# Back bar button item with right button

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented a right item button in the navigation bar. I use the storyboard, no code. But now the back button is not displayed. What's the good way to show it again without boilerplate code ?

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: once you navigate through one viewcontroller to another, it will automatically add the back button

Comment: just run your app and navigate to some viewController, back button will appear automatically

Comment: yes but here I added a right button item, so the back button disappeared. I add an other screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can not see the back button on the `rootViewController` of the `NavigationController`
- `NavigationController` automatically add the back button once you push some other `ViewController` to it.
- It will display if you have not hides it explicitly.
- If you have drag and drop the `BarButtonItem` as shown in the attached image, Just run the code and back button will automatically get added if it was not your `RootViewController`.
- If it is `RootViewController` as displayed in images, try to push some ViewController on it, you will get the back button added.
- If you add the left bar button item from Interface Builder, you will not get the back button displayed. Then you have to do it manually

Comment: see my 2 screenshots, the back button is gone now that I added the right button item

Comment: Just remove the left bar button item

Comment: how ? it's not clickable http://i.stack.imgur.com/53H4H.png there is not button on the "left bar button items"

Comment: Hi You dont need to do anything. Just the code, and back button will automatically get added to your view controller if it was not rootviewcontroller

Comment: Ok, I juste removed the navigation controller, and it's work, thank you !

Comment: Why you removed that?

Comment: You removed navigation controller or navigation item?

Comment: the navigation controller before my view

Comment: Then how you have create your back button? Custom? and how you are navigating to other viewcontroller?

Comment: Well that not my part of business. You would know better what you require to use in app  :) Happy coding

Comment: I have already a navigation controller at the start of the app. Thank you =)